# cakePHP3: How to send parameters to an action via redirect()?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In an action, I want to send send parameters to another action via redirect.

So as I read this in the documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages):

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $id]);
```

I wrote:

```
public function activate($user_id, $token) {

    //.... of course $user->username is not null here
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login', $user->username]);

    //....
}
```

And in my target action:

```
public function login($username = null) {

    //...

    debug($username);  // just displays null

    //...
}
```

I don't understand if the problem is in redirect() or in login(). Anyway debug($this->request) doesn't show any passed parameters.

Regards,

Comment: What exactly is the problem, the username not being added to the generated URL, or the value not being passed to the method altough it's present in the URL?

Comment: I don't really know ndm but it does not appear in the url but I think that username is not supposed to be passed as querystring anyway and I don't see it in params so I don't it's not transfered at all.

Comment: Well, if the username doesn't appear in the URL, then it's the former. Does it work with a hardcoded string, like `['action' => 'login', 'foobar']`? There's not much I can think of that could be responsible for that behavior, other then invalid values or conflicting routes. So if it also doesn't work with a hardcoded string, try removing all but the default routes, also make sure that you have the latest CakePHP version (`composer update`).

Comment: So, if I use redirect(['action' => 'login', 'username' => $user->username]);, I can get the username as query string so, I'll do like that, it's ok for what I want to do. Thks ndm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above code only works if the login function is in the same controller and you do not need to return.
else we need to define the controller as well for the redirect. Like :

```
$this->redirect(['controller'=>'YourController','action' => 'login', $user->username]);
```